# Is there a limit to how many declared variables I can have in the SQLCommand area of an OLE DB Command task?

Tags: sql, ssis, oledbcommand

I am trying to capture which records were deleted between our on-prem staging and dbo tables before they get deleted, so that we can pass that information to azure sql and delete them in the corresponding tables there. To do this, I added a step to our SSIS package that is handling the on-prem CDC - basically an OLE DB command task with a sql command that inserts the key values of records that are about to be deleted into a separate table. This works great for any table that has 2 or fewer keys. As soon as I try to apply the same logic to a table with 3+ keys, I get a 'statement(s) could not be prepared' error.

I am guessing there is some kind of limit on how many variables I can set within the sqlCommand field, but is there a way around this?

my logic in the SQLCommand looks something like this:

```
`DECLARE @P3 AS INT = ? 
DECLARE @P4 AS SMALLINT = ? 
DECLARE @P5 AS SMALLINT = ? 
DECLARE @P6 AS CHAR(1) = ? 

INSERT INTO stage.records_to_delete
VALUES(‘table_name’, CONCAT(‘delete <table_name> WHERE key1 = ‘’’, @P3, ‘’’ AND key2 = ‘’’, @P4,     ‘’’ AND key3 = ‘’’, @P5, ‘’’ AND key4 = ‘’’, @P6, ‘’’), getdate())`
```

This inserts the table name, a sql statement to delete the particular record, and the date into my deleted records table.

What I have tried:

- Running the sql in SSMS - it works like a charm, so I know it's not a syntax error.
- Manually creating the OLE DB Command Input External Columns - I hoped this would bypass the issue, but it resulted in the same error.
- Tested to make sure it wasn't a specific datatype that I was setting a variable to that was causing the problem. Each works fine individually, just not in groups of 3+.

Comment: Your query example not readable. Symbols ``‘’’`` - what is realy? Part ``, @P6, ‘’’)`` can produce error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My original assumption was this was going to have something to do with how SQL Server handle's parameterized statements. If you turn on a trace/extended event, you'll see it uses the P0, P1 etc nomenclature and you can then get a conflict if you use them along with ... sp_execute_sql or something like that, details are hazy.

My first failed attempt was to merely rename your parameters like the following

```
DECLARE
    @SSIS_P0 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P1 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P2 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P3 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P4 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P5 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P6 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P7 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P8 int = ?
,   @SSIS_P9 int = ?
,   @table_name sysname = 'SO_';
INSERT INTO stage.records_to_delete
VALUES(@table_name, CONCAT('delete ', @table_name, ' WHERE key0 = ''', @SSIS_P0, ''' '
, ' AND key1 = ''', @SSIS_P1, ''' '
, ' AND key2 = ''', @SSIS_P2, ''' '
, ' AND key3 = ''', @SSIS_P3, ''' '
, ' AND key4 = ''', @SSIS_P4, ''' '
, ' AND key5 = ''', @SSIS_P5, ''' '
, ' AND key6 = ''', @SSIS_P6, ''' '
, ' AND key7 = ''', @SSIS_P7, ''' '
, ' AND key8 = ''', @SSIS_P8, ''' '
, ' AND key9 = ''', @SSIS_P9, ''' '
), getdate());
```

The OLE DB Command component rejects that with

> Error at DFT Do the thing [OLE DB Command [46]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax error or access violation".

But it's as you say, replace the `?` with values and run in SSMS and it works.

Thinking harder about the problem, there's no need to use OLE DB Command, that I can infer from your problem statement. The need is to store an arbitrary string that into a column. It'd be nice to figure out *why* the OLE DB Command isn't acting as I'd expect it but we can solve this a different way.

### OLE DB Source

Assume I have a source component (ole/ado/odbc) that issues the following query to a SQL Server

```
SELECT 0 AS Col0
, 1 AS Col1
, 2 As Col2
, 3 AS Col3
, 4 AS Col4
, 5 As Col5
, 6 As Col6
, 7 As Col7
, 8 As Col8
, 9 As Col9
, N'Foo' AS table_name
, CAST(getdate() As datetime2(0)) AS insert_date;
```

### Multicast

Add a multi-cast into your data flow whenever you have enough information to insert data into your stage.records_to_delete table.  A multicast allows you to have a parallel stream of operations without incurring memory costs to double the data.

Here, we're going to let the rest of your data flow do whatever it was doing and add a new branch to solve the "capturing arbitrary keys problem"

### Derived Column

As we were already building the delete statement manually, instead of using a mix of SQL and SSIS, just use the SSIS Expression language to build it.

```
"delete " + table_name + " WHERE key0 = '" + (DT_WSTR,100)Col0 + "' " 
+ " AND key1 = '" + (DT_WSTR,100)Col1 + "' "
+ " AND key2 = '" + (DT_WSTR,100)Col2 + "' "
...
+ " AND key9 = '" + (DT_WSTR,100)Col9 + "' "
```

The Derived Column component doesn't actually accept line breaks as shown above, whereas you *can* use them with Variables. But the line breaks here are to show the pattern, along with the ellipses `...`

Reading that, we concatenate `+` strings along with the columns from our data source. As we could have a variety of types, I explicitly cast the columns to a unicode string of length 100 `(DT_WSTR, 100) ColName`

@billinkc, I'm going to downvote because you're demonstrating something that is subject to SQL Injection. Yup, I am. Carry on, that's not the problem we're solving. This pattern *is* subject to bad escaping if the source data is already a string and contains a single quote but given the samples, I'm not worried about it.

If your source component does not have the table_name and insert_date or their equivalent in it, then you'll want to address that here.

Add another column to the Derived Column component call it something like `insert_date` and use `@[System::StartTime]` as the expression. This is analogous to get_date but it will now be a column in our data flow.

Add a column for your table_name if you want a really flexible approach. I hard coded table_name as "Foo" in the source query. Solve as you wish.

The need is for all 3 columns to be defined at this point in the data flow so the next component can operate.

### OLE DB Destination

Rather than dealing with OLE DB Command, which issues a statement per row flowing through it, let's use a component which is designed for sending batches of inserts, like our friend OLE DB Destination.

In the Name of table or view, choose [stage].[records_to_delete]

In the Columns tab, I map my 3 columns to our destination

[image]